# How can I delete one product from localhost array saver and move all table in middle page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have to do a table with products add to wishlist, and a button in the right row table side, which deletes only one selected product, not all

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
  <div className="container-13">
    <Table className="tabletable" sx={{minWidth: 650 }} arial-labe="simple table">
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell></TableCell>
          <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Image</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Product name</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Unit price</TableCell>
          <TableCell></TableCell>
          <TableCell></TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {wishlist.map((product) => (
        <TableRow key={product.id}>
          <TableCell></TableCell>
          <TableCell>{product.id}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>
            <img className="imagesTable" src={product.image} alt={product.title}/>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>{product.title}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>${product.price}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>
            <button className="buttonDelete" onClick={()=>handleDeleteFromWish(product.id)}>Delete</button>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </div>
</TableContainer>
```

here is the function delete

```
function deleteWish(product) {
  const wishlist = getWishlist();
  const updateWish = wishlist.filter((product) => product.id !== product.id);
  saveWish(updateWish);
}
```

also, I try to move the table in middle, but doesn't work:

```
.container-13{
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.buttonDelete{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.tabletable{
    align-content: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

I don't know how to make this work, I tried different things..

Comment: Your `.filter` inside `deleteWish` does nothing; why are you comparing each `product.id !== product.id` that's always `false`, try: `... wishlist.filter((p) => p.id !== product.id); ...`.

Comment: it's perfect, thanks! 
now all I need to do is to put the table in the middle, but not even now Idk doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

To center, you can use flexbox in the container: display:flex; align-ítems: center; justify-content: center;